# Interactive map of Albania

Tags: jquery, xml, html, svg

I want to create an interactive map like this http://www.tring.al/harta.html using jQuery and SVG but I don't know where to start. I have the map as .svg.xml (link here: [albania.xml](http://www.tring.al/mapalbania/maps/albania.svg)) But what to do next. Can anyone help me what should I do next?

[Albania interactive map](http://www.tring.al/harta.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this code (I got it out of Google Maps)

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3062273.914005372!2d20.116626437500003!3d41.45002910144466!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x13453bf3bd274c2d%3A0x77ce589d6983bee!2sAlbania!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1409673218830"
    width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the flashy design on the example site is done in css.

one of the shapes looks like this:

`<a xlink:href="../hartalezha.html" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><path fill="#84d858" stroke="#ffffff" d="**Removed points**" stroke-width="3.5200000000000005" stroke-linejoin="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: default; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path></a>`

The css takes care of the hovering actions such as color change etc.
Here the html directly deals with a redirect on a click (no fancy jQuery).

The only jQuery would would need is a listener for shapes being clicked if you want to do something extra without a redirect.

Edit:
here is a possible css for the path tag:

```
path{
fill: rgb(64, 129, 195);
stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
stroke-width: 3.5200000000000005px;
stroke-linejoin: round;
}

path:hover{
 fill: rgb(225,0, 129, 100);
}
```

This will overwrite the fill color on hover of an individual shape.

Comment: Thank you but can you show me an example how to do an hover state for a particualr city? should I use clip or what?

Comment: Each city is a path tag so simply having a path:hover style in css will work. If you say wanted to have a list of cities on a menu, and have the city highlighted when you clicked the name you would need javascript. In that case I would give each path an id="city_name" and add an on_click(toggle("city_name") function.